# higher order component can't see props

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, redux, react-redux

I'm using react with react-native and redux. The error comes to the component from the redux store. After that, i received: Nothing was returned from render. This usually means a return statement is missing. Or, to render nothing, return null.

What is wrong with this? why hoc can't see the props?

My component:

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import withHandleError from './withHandleError';

class SendScreen extends Component {

  render() {
    const { error } = this.props;
    return (
    <div> Test </div>
    )
  }
};

const mapStateToProps = ({ppm}) => ({
  error: ppm.error
})


export default withHandleError(connect(mapStateToProps)(SendScreen));
```

And HoC:

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { ErrorScreen } from '../../ErrorScreen';
import { View } from 'react-native';

export default Cmp => {
  return class extends Component {
    render() {
      const {error, ...rest } = this.props;
      console.log(error)  //// undefined....
      if (error) {
        return <ErrorScreen />
      }

      return <Cmp { ...rest } />
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you show the redux logic please?

Answer (score 0):

The order is which you call the HOCs matters when you want to access props supplied by one in another. Re-ordering your connect and withHandleError HOC will work

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import withHandleError from './withHandleError';

class SendScreen extends Component {

  render() {
    const { error } = this.props;
    return (
    <div> Test </div>
    )
  }
};

const mapStateToProps = ({ppm}) => ({
  error: ppm.error
})


export default connect(mapStateToProps)(withHandleError(SendScreen));
```

Comment: Thank you! It works! It is possible to pass value from SendScreen state to HoC WithHandleError? For example i Have error not i component props but in component state?

Comment: Not unless you pass a callback method from parent as props which you can invoke from child